# Create Cache file

Tags: java, android, directory

I was trying to create cache folder in code below one time create folder but after reinstall app cache directory was not create i was giving  read and write storage permission but they show me error like Directory doesn't exist & Couldn't create .nomedia file, i am new in developing field so please give me suggestion

```
public class CacheStore {

private static final String cacheDir = "/Android/data/"+ BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"/cache/";
private static final String CACHE_FILENAME = ".cache";

public CacheStore() {
   File fullCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),cacheDir);
   if(!fullCacheDir.exists()) {
      Log.i("CACHE", "Directory doesn't exist");
      cleanCacheStart();
      return;
   }
}

 private void cleanCacheStart() {
    cacheMap = new HashMap\<String, String\>();
    File fullCacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(),cacheDir);
    fullCacheDir.mkdirs();
    File noMedia = new File(fullCacheDir.toString(), ".nomedia");
    try {
       noMedia.createNewFile();
       Log.i("CACHE", "Cache created");
     } catch (IOException e) { 
       Log.i("CACHE", "Couldn't create .nomedia file");
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `String cacheDir = "/Android/data/"+ BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"/cache/";` Wrong approach. Dont hardcode that path. Its even not complete as it should start with /storage/emulated/0. Have a look at getExternalCacheDir() instead.

Comment: And you do not need any permission to get access to your apps private directories.

Comment: `fullCacheDir.mkdirs();` Never blindly call mkdirs() but only if the directory does not exist yet. `if (!fullCach.exists()) if (!fullCacheDir.mkdirs()) return false;`

Comment: noMedia.createNewFile(); will not throw. It will return true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to create cache file then, use Context.getCacheDir(); method.
**Note that : The system will automatically delete files in this directory as disk space is needed elsewhere on the device.**

try this

```
public class CacheStore {
    private Context context;
    private File cacheDir;

    public CacheStore(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        File noMedia=new File(cacheDir,".nomedia");
        if (!noMedia.exists()){
            try {
                noMedia.createNewFile();
                Log.i("CACHE", "Cache created");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("CACHE", "Couldn't create .nomedia file");
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```